# Email sent confirmation in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am the tech-support for my 93-year old grandpa. He starts to have difficulties with sending emails.
He says everytime he wants to send an email it suddenly is gone. Of course it's not, he just thinks it is and then calls me all upset.
So my question is, is there an Addon for Thunderbird that just opens a pop-up dialog after the email has been sent saying "Email sent"?
All i found is confirmation dialoges *before* sending but not after.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: For me, thunderbird reports successful sending of an email in the sending dialog that opens while sending. It says "Mail sent successfully", but it only displays very shortly (less than a second actually) so that's hard to pay attention to. Maybe you can tell him to check the "sent" folder in case he is unsure?

Comment: I would like to add that usually after replying to a mail a "replied" icon appears next to the mail in the overview, maybe you can point him in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird *Account Settings*, *Copies & Folders*, an email address can be specified to receive "carbon copies" on sending a message.

[image: Setting Sent Mail CC:]

This might be of help in two ways:

- If an alternate account for your father is set, and alerts are set on receiving a message, he'll get notified when the mail goes into the alternate account, and it will be shown in **bold** until read.
- If he doesn't mind your looking at his mail, you could also get an alert, so that should he be concerned, you can confirm it was sent.

A possible *disadvantage* is that confirmation may take a few minutes. The delay can be made shorter by adjusting *Check for mail every xx minutes* in the  *Server Settings* for the account set to receive the Cc:, but cannot be completely eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Or change account settings to put sent mail in the Inbox. Then sent messages immediately appear in the folder that grandpa is accustomed to looking at, no CC required.